# regular expressions mysql 5.1

Tags: mysql

For some reason this regular expression is not working

clientcode REGEXP '^[A-E]'

where i want it to return all clientcodes that start with letters between A to E.

it used to work in the old application now I'm putting it with mysql 5.1 and its not working.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me:

```
SELECT VERSION(), 'Bar' REGEXP '^[A-E]', 'Foo' REGEXP '^[A-E]';
+------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| VERSION()                          | 'Bar' REGEXP '^[A-E]' | 'Foo' REGEXP '^[A-E]' |
+------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| 5.1.55-enterprise-gpl-advanced-log |                     1 |                     0 | 
+------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```